# Connection Timeout on mounting nfs via azure blob storage

Tags: linux, rhel

So I am following this document on Mount Blob Storage with NFS and I am having an issue mounting my storage and container.
This is the document I am following

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/network-file-system-protocol-support-how-to

```
 mount -o sec=sys,vers=3,nolock,proto=tcp testnfstwo.blob.core.windows.net:/testnfstwo/yocontainer  /NFSSHARE
mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```